# Did Wolverine fight in WWII with Capt America?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

In a few of the Marvel back stories, it's shown that Wolverine fought alongside The Cap during WWII.

Is this ever acknowledged in the Marvel movie franchises?

Comment: no that was just a funny cameo

Comment: @avenge Funny cameo?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Marvel properties adapted before the invention of [Marvel Studios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Studios) are not linked to the current shared [Marvel Cinematic Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe) due to rights ownership. This includes that the film rights for characters in Blade, X-Men, Spider-Man, Ghost Rider, Daredevil, Punisher and Fantastic Four are owned by other movie studios (how Marvel roped *Incredible Hulk* into the shared universe after the initial *Hulk* movie, I do not know; both Hulk movies were distributed by Universal though).

However, the same does not apply to the Marvel television series [The Super Hero Squad Show](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Super_Hero_Squad_Show) and [Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers:_Earth%27s_Mightiest_Heroes), both of which are produced by [Marvel Animation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Animation). In *Super Hero Squad Show*, Wolverine and the X-Men appear regularly alongside Iron Man, Hulk, Captain America and the Silver Surfer. The only character obviously missing is Spider-Man. The [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Super_Hero_Squad_Show#Cast) says:

> Marvel initially intended to put Spider-Man in at least one episode of the show, but Sony Pictures Entertainment (then-owners of Spider-Man's television rights) possibly chose not to lend the rights. However, Spider-Man appeared in Marvel Super Hero Squad's video games and other tie-ins. Spider-Man was later briefly mentioned in "Election of Evil" as "a guy who got incredible powers for being bitten by a radioactive bug".

This intermingling of properties also happened in the Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes cartoon, which shows Wolverine fighting alongside Captain America in World War II.

This is a still from the episode:
[image]

So to answer the question, no, Wolverine was not shown fighting alongside Cap in the Captain America movie because of movie rights. BUT he has been shown to fight alongside Cap on TV, due to assumed differences in rights between television and film rights.

Comment: Spider-man has been in EMH in season 2 ^_^

Comment: Btw, even in X-Men Evolution, Wolverine mentioned that he fought alongside Captain America. But like you said, this is completely dependent on Marvel's ridiculously convoluted ownership issues regarding their characters. Whoever own's both Cap and Logan would show them both fight together if they want to.

Comment: Marvel really needs to get their act together and sort out these ownership rights. I fail to understand how the Marvel company is not allowed to make movies about Marvel characters, how could they possibly have let other companies buy it out from under them?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Captain America and Wolverine fight alongside each other briefly during WW2. However Wolverine gets transfered to another unit before he can complete more than three missons with Captain America.

I know there are some good comics explaining this but it takes a while to find them and then finally understand them. The comics showing them fighting together are a back issue though, about WW2.

The comic actually has Stan Lee and the father of Nick Fury in them. Stan Lee and Conlel Fury fight with Captain America, Bucky, and Wolverine. Conlel Fury ends up losing his eye and Stan Lee dies. Wolverine tries to save Stan Lee but fails. He takes it out on Bucky and requests a transfer to a new unit. Wolverine spends the rest of the war out in his new unit, eventually becoming a higher rank than Cap. Bucky supposedly dies, and Cap gets frozen after deactivating a nuclear bomb sent off by the The Red Skulls scientists and followers.

Wolverine is actually part of the assult team on the castle Bucky and Cap are attacking but Wolverine doesn't follow Cap to the bomb. He instead follows Bucky under Cap's and General Fury's orders. Wolverine sees Bucky follow another missile but he doesn't deactivate it until over Russia. Russians find Bucky, erase his memory, implant new memories of him as a Russian and he becomes the Winter Soldier. His main goal is to destroy America and anybody else who gets in his way.

Wolverine goes on to the war in Japan after the assult on the castle. WW2 follows on out in Germany while Wolverine gets drafted into Japan. There he meets his one true love and marries her. After while she dies of cancer and he moves on to the war in Viet Nahm. He gets arrested and a year later he gets adamantium put on his bones.

I hope that helped.

Comment: My question was about the movies, not the comics. I know that it happened in the comics. But thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

The movies form a separate continuity from the comics.  So, no, this is unlikely.  The X-men movies don't seem to exist in the same continuity as the 'Avengers' movie lines (*Thor, Hulk, Iron Man, Captain America*) either.

It's still possible (remotely) that the X-Men trilogy is in the same continuity, but I think that's unlikely - there are big events in those which we never see referenced in the other movies, and the other movies reference each other in minor ways.

Answer (score 0):

look up the cartoon series "X-Men: Evolution"

In the episode "Operation Rebirth," through flashbacks Wolverine and Captain America are depicted fighting alongside each other in WWII. They're also portrayed as good friends, but in this universe, (at present) Captain America was frozen in a cryogenic chamber (in S.H.I.E.L.D.), waiting for them to find a cure to the damage done by Rebirth.

I found this relationship to be almost heartbreaking, and it would be nice to see it expanded upon in movie version ... but I don't think that will happen due to different people owning different rights to different things