# Wolverine teams up with Captain America in WWII

Tags: story-identification, captain-america, wolverine

I am looking for a team up comic I had (I looked through all of my boxes and it was suspiciously missing). It has Wolverine and Captain America working together in WWII and I believe it was described in an answer on this post but the comic was not specified:

[Did Wolverine fight in WWII with Capt America?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6138/did-wolverine-fight-in-wwii-with-capt-america)

At the end of the story Cap tells Logan that they made a good team and should team up. Logan tells him that he does not need a sidekick and Cap smiles because he was asking Logan to be the sidekick. I tried searching on fandom without success. I am also not sure if this was a Wolverine title or a Captain America title. Who has the answer?

Comment: It reminds me of an episode of X-Men Evolution in which Logan reminds having teamed up with Captain in a flashback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[*Uncanny X-Men Volume 1, Issue 268*](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Uncanny_X-Men_Vol_1_268)

[image: Wolverine and Captain America fighting together]

[This Screenrant article](https://screenrant.com/captain-america-wolverine-world-war-2/) mentions the sidekick line

> The conflict is obviously Steve Rogers' domain in Marvel history, fighting many adventures, both domestic and overseas, to combat the Nazis and their subdivision Hydra. One such mission was showcased in Uncanny X-Men #268, where Captain America teamed up with a Russian Agent, Ivan Petrovich, to rescue a young girl kidnapped under Ivan's watchful eye. However, Cap. and Ivan encounter trouble early on in the case when they come up against the Hand, an elite group of Ninja who never leave behind a body. When the odds seem stacked against the two, they receive help from an unexpected ally by the name of Logan.

....

> During the rescue, Wolverine is shot and presumed dead by Captain America and Ivan, having used his body to shield Natasha. However, thanks to Wolverine's healing factor, he manages to survive the attack and subsequently fend off both Hydra and the Hand. Cap I understandably impressed with Wolverine's skills and offers a partnership, which Wolverine politely declines, citing his disinterest in "a sidekick."

[image: Dialogue referencing who'd be whose sidekick]

`wolverine "captain america" sidekick` brought up the Screen Rant article, which led me to the panel in [this review](https://youtu.be/YtbVEOemH-s?t=478).

Comment: And that explains why I could not find it. I was expecting it outside of a regular xmen comic.